# Шифруются ли данные при использовании WMI?

Tags: windows, шифрование, wmi

Я использую WMI запросы для получения данных об удаленных компьютерах, но передача данных должна быть защищена. На вики и msdn'е я ничего подходящего не нашёл, но должна же винда как - то шифровать эти данные. Где можно узнать как она это делает, ну или не делает? Никогда не думал о таких вещах, поэтому прощу прощения, если вопрос глупый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/439756-wmi-traffice-encrypted) задавали подробный вопрос. Если верить ответу, то шифруется только аутентификация посредством Kerberos. Сами запросы не шифруются